# Angular 2 how to make CustomValueAccessor validatable?

Tags: angular

I have a DateOfBirth component that implements **CustomValueAccessor**.

It is instantiated as follows:

```
<div class="form-group" [fieldValidity]="dateOfBirth">
  <label for="name" class="sr-only">Date of birth</label>
  <date-of-birth
    required
    ngDefaultControl
    [(ngModel)]="model.dateOfBirth"
    #dateOfBirth="ngModel"
    name="dateOfBirth">
  </date-of-birth>
  <field-validation-messages field="dateOfBirth"></field-validation-messages>
```

**Field-validation-messages** uses field parameter to access `.errors.required` However it's parameter only resolves to a string "dateOfBirth" rather than the control object.

How can I make this control validatable?

For reference, here is the component code:

```
const noop = () => {
};
export const CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => DateOfBirth),
  multi: true
};
@Component({
  moduleId: __moduleName,
  selector: 'date-of-birth',
  templateUrl: 'date_of_birth.html',
  styleUrls: ['date_of_birth.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  providers: [CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class DateOfBirth implements ControlValueAccessor {

  @Input() name: string;

  private _viewModel: DateOfBirthVm = new DateOfBirthVm();

  private _yearOptions: Array<number> = [];
  private _monthInputValue: string = '';
  private _monthControl: FormControl = new FormControl();
  private _yearInputValue: string = '';
  private _yearControl: FormControl = new FormControl();

  constructor(private _appSettings: AppSettings) {
    this._monthControl.valueChanges.subscribe((value: string) => {
      this._viewModel.month = value;
      this._onChanged(this._viewModel);
    });
    this._yearControl.valueChanges.subscribe((value: string) => {
      this._viewModel.year = value;
      this._onChanged(this._viewModel);
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    for(let i=(this._appSettings.currentYear-18); i>1909; i--) {
      this._yearOptions.push(i);
    }
  }

  //Interface specific stuff.
  //To notify external component's that the model has changed, we must call our
  //registeredOnChange handler. (e.g _onChanged()). Simply calling it, informs other components.
  registerOnChange(fn: any) { this._onChanged = fn; }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any) { this._onTouched = fn; }
  private _onChanged = (value) => { };
  private _onTouched = () => { };
  //write value is called when an external component writes to our model.
  //e.g if another component with ([ngModel])="myAutoCompleteValue", calls myAutoCompleteValue = '';
  writeValue(vm: DateOfBirthVm) {
    if(!vm) {
      this._viewModel.month = '';
      this._viewModel.year = '';
    } else {
      this._viewModel = vm;
      this._monthInputValue = vm.month;
      this._yearInputValue = vm.year;
      this._onChanged(vm);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Field-validation-messages uses field parameter to access .errors.required However it's parameter only resolves to a string "dateOfBirth" rather than the control object.

```
<field-validation-messages field="dateOfBirth"></field-validation-messages>
```

You need the brackets (`[]`) around `field` or else it will not be evaluated. Just the string `dateOfBirth` will be used.

Here's from the [Angular docs on template syntax](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#property-binding)

> #### Remember the brackets
>
> The brackets tell Angular to evaluate the template expression. If we forget the brackets, Angular treats the string as a constant and initializes the target property with that string. It does not evaluate the string!
>
> Don't make the following mistake:
>
> ```
> <!-- ERROR: HeroDetailComponent.hero expects a
> Hero object, not the string "currentHero" -->
> <hero-detail hero="currentHero"></hero-detail>
> ```

Comment: Fantastic thank you! Totally missed the square brackets, should have figured that one out >< haha.